# how to add warning when closing single tab? (explorer/chrome)

Tags: browser, tabs

[picture from explorer internet options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knWzz.png)

"warn me when closing multiple tabs" - how to change it for one tab only?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to tell Internet Explorer to warn the user when they attempt to close one tab. If you often find yourself closing tabs by accident, pressing `Ctrl + Shift + T` on Windows or `Cmd + Shift + T` on a Mac will reopen the most recently closed tab. Hopefully that helps!